# Running a function x times asynchronously in a for loop in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, axios

I have a switch with cases in it, in this case I want to run `axios.get()` X amount of times, I'm trying to do it with this:

```
          case "visit":
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < JSON.parse(cmd).contents.threads; i++) {
          let i;
          for (i = 0; i < JSON.parse(cmd).contents.visits; i++) {
            console.log(i + 1 + " visits run!");
            axios.get(JSON.parse(cmd).contents.target).then(res => {});
            if (i === JSON.parse(cmd).contents.visits - 1) {
              console.log("Visiting complete!");
            }
          }
        }
        break;
```

The thing is it doesn't run asynchronously and give me the results afterwards, the output looks like this:

```
1 visits run!
2 visits run!
3 visits run!
4 visits run!
5 visits run!
6 visits run!
7 visits run!
8 visits run!
9 visits run!
10 visits run!
Visiting complete!
1 visits run!
2 visits run!
3 visits run!
4 visits run!
5 visits run!
6 visits run!
7 visits run!
8 visits run!
9 visits run!
10 visits run!
Visiting complete!
```

all at once, so this isn't running async, any suggestions how I should run this async? I'm trying to learn async in node this way and hope to accomplish this.

Oh and before I forget, here's the js object of cmd

```
 {
  id: "002",
  app: "visit",
  contents: {
    target: "https://google.com/",
    visits: 10,
    threads: 2
  }
```

Comment: The accepted answer, although it shows off async code fine, doesn't use your definition of threads or anything. Instead, all 20 requests (10 visits * 2 threads) are run at the same time. If you're ok with that that's fine obviously, but just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because all of your output is being sent to the console within the synchronous execution of the loop. You're starting the asynchronous request in the background, but you don't supply a callback that does anything after the request is completed. You should output to the console within the function you pass to `then()`.

Here's an example:

```
const contents = JSON.parse(cmd).contents;

for (let i = 0; i < contents.threads; i++) {
  let count = 0;

  for (let j = 0; j < contents.visits; j++) {
    axios.get(contents.target).then(result => {
      const number = ++count;

      console.log(number + " visits run!");
      if(number == contents.visits) console.log("Visiting complete!");
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
/////////
// option 1:
// To make this run sequentially
let p = Promise.resolve();
for (i = 0; i < JSON.parse(cmd).contents.visits; i++) {
  p = p.then(() => axios.get(JSON.parse(cmd).contents.target).then(res => { /* do whatever */});
}
p.then(() => {
    //all stuff done
})

//////
// option 2:
// To make this run in parallel (keeping your for loop, etc. (hint: using map would be more concise: 
const promises = [];
for (i = 0; i < JSON.parse(cmd).contents.visits; i++) {
  promises.push(axios.get(JSON.parse(cmd).contents.target).then(res => { /* do whatever */}));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    //all stuff done
})
```

Comment: I don't really understand, this code doesn't contain my threads key in it, thereby ignoring the fact that i'm trying to run the visits (say 100) x3 simultaniously by running the function async. thus resulting in 300 visits within 1/3'd of the current timespan, basically what multithreading would do in c++ (example)

I don't really understand what you are trying to do with your code, so if you could elaborate on that that would be great.

Comment: Ahh that wasnt clear to me. So basically you want to run 300 requests, but keep parallel requests to 3 max?

Comment: Yes, sorry, reading back the thread I wasn't very clear myself in want I wanted to do, I'm going to test the other answer now, thanks for your help anyways!